How to use office 365 outlook for email services using C#
I am using outlook.office365.com email, but getting remove connectivity error
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException HResult=0x80131500 Message=Failure sending mail.

Source=EmailTesting

Inner Exception 1: WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server

Inner Exception 2: SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 52.101.145.0:587

my code below :
var sClient = new SmtpClient("domainname-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"); // This is MX code,     used with smtp.office365.com and outlook.office365.com.. still same error
var message = new MailMessage();

sClient.Port = 587;
sClient.EnableSsl = true;
sClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("from-email", "Password");
sClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

message.Body = "Test";
message.From = new MailAddress("from-email");
message.Subject = "Test";
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("Receiver-email"));

sClient.Send(message);


Are you sure that's the correct SMTP server? According to this it should be smtp-mail.outlook.com

Check if it smtp server is correct and also the port. I dont think that you can just use the mail like that without disabling some security settings in outlook

You may need to create an app password to access this unless you can interactively authenticate yourself to outlook in your app using "OAuth2/Modern Auth" authentication.

I tried with this as well "smtp-mail.outlook.com"

Did you get the same error?

getthing this error below : System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. [BMXPR01CA0077.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-10-25T13:11:10.673Z 08DCF4B0F52199EE]'

That looks like progress. You are now connecting to the actual SMTP server but unable to authenticate. Did you take a look at the link in my original comment that states "Outlook.com requires the use of Modern Auth / OAuth2.  Basic auth is in the process of being deprecated from the Outlook.com service."?

I have verified this Modern Auth  / OAuth2., this is already enabled in admin center. is there anything i need to change in my code or portal.

Since you're getting authentication failures now, I expect that you will have to. Have you tried creating an "app password" and using that?

App password is already there..do i need to create another one.. if i create new app password, it can impact all emails.. right ?
